# I cannot find the /mnt/sdcard/ folder in my android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdcard

I am trying to create a dynamic media browser that takes mp3 files from an sd card and generates a list of songs to browse through.

My issue is that I cannot find the /mnt/sdcard folder. Inside /mnt/ I have an sdcard.img, but I am not sure how to use it.

Here is most of the information that I know:

- I am using the latest version of android studio
- I have set the emulator up with a Studio-managed 1000m SD card
- I formatted the SD card when I got the notification on the emulator, using internal storage.

Comment: What does [`getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) return? And when you are not using it: Why?

Answer (score 1):

Google Before Asking...

1. Select Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor
2. Goto File Explorer Tab

[image: AVD]

3. Browse mnt/sdcard OR storage/sdcard
4. See top-right corner(Small Mobile icons)
5. Use that icons to push and pull file from the device. It doesn't support drag and drop

Comment: This is my issue. I do not have an SDcard folder to push files into. I just have the image file, that I am unable to push into